# Why does va_start fail?

Tags: c++, windows, macros

I want to create some logging, and i made a class. However i have some problem with passing the arguments to it.

Class:

```
namespace debug
{
    class log
    {
        private:    // Members
            const std::string context;
            int Type;
        public:     // Methods
            void message( int Type, const std::string& message, ... );

        public:     // Constructor, Destructor
            log( const std::string& context, int Type );
            ~log();
    };//class log
}//namespace debug     

namespace debug
{
    void log::message( int Type, const std::string& message, ... )
    {
        va_list args;
        int len;

        char    *buffer;

        va_start( args, message );

        len = _vscprintf( message.c_str(), args ) + 1; // _vscprintf doesn't count terminating '\0'
        buffer = ( char* )malloc( len * sizeof( char ) );

        vsprintf_s( buffer, len, message.c_str(), args );

        va_end( args );

    }//log::message
}//namespace debug
```

I have two macros defined:

```
#define DEBUG_METHOD( Type )  debug::log _debugLog( __FUNCTION__, Type );
#define DEBUG_MESSAGE( Type, debug_message, ... ) { _debugLog.message( Type, debug_message, ##__VA_ARGS__ ); }
```

And i use them in a Function like this:

```
BOOL test( BOOL *bTestVal)
{
   DEBUG_METHOD( INFO );
   DEBUG_MESSAGE( INFO, "Argument1 = '%s'", BoolToString( ( BOOL )*bTestVal) );

       //here comes some work...
}
```

Unfortunately i always get an error. This line `len = _vscprintf( message.c_str(), args ) + 1;` always throws an error. I think `va_start` is causing this, becasue `args` has a value of `+        args    0x0052eed8 "ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ... char *`

Could someone please help me what i am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does your BoolToString() return ? And are you certain your compiler supports the `##__VA_ARGS__` construct ?

Comment: This is the BoolToString: `char * const BoolToString( BOOL b )
{
 return b ? "True" : "False";
}//BoolToString`

Comment: @nos:no, i'm not certain. I didn't used this kind of macro until now. I use Visual Studio 2013 Express.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **18.10/3** ...The parameter `parmN` is the identifier of the rightmost parameter in the variable parameter list of the function definition (the one just before the ...). If the parameter `parmN` is declared with a function, array, or **reference type**, or with a type that is not compatible with the type that results when passing an argument for which there is no parameter, **the behavior is undefined**.

Emphasis mine.

Comment: Note: With parmN the parameter of funtion 'va_start' is ment.

`void va_start (va_list ap, paramN);`

Answer (score 4):

Igor already provided you with formal quote, and here is a code snippet that shows what happens exactly, with Visual C++. The thing is that `va_start` needs to advance pointer to skip the parameter at which it starts, and while reference is effectively passed as pointer, skipping size is taken as full size of the argument. This advances the pointer much farther than you expect.

Compare using `va_start` against `A*` and `A&` below:

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    char B[1024];
};

void C(int f, A* a, ...)
{
    va_list Arguments;
    va_start(Arguments, a);
    int d = va_arg(Arguments, int);
    _tprintf(_T("0x%p, 0x%p, %d, %d\n"), &f, Arguments, (char*) &f - (char*) Arguments, d);
}

void E(int f, A& a, ...)
{
    va_list Arguments;
    va_start(Arguments, a);
    int d = va_arg(Arguments, int);
    _tprintf(_T("0x%p, 0x%p, %d, %d\n"), &f, Arguments, (char*) &f - (char*) Arguments, d);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    A a;
    C(0, &a, 1234);
    E(0, a, 1234);
```

The output you get is about this:

```
0x0018F9E0, 0x0018F9EC, -12, 1234
0x0018F9E0, 0x0018FEC0, -1248, -858993460
```

Both function have their stack frame start at the same address (expectedly) and then va_start's result moves the pointer by different distance, which correlates with size of `A` class (12 vs. 1248).

This is why you cannot use va_start with argument of reference type: it cannot properly skip the variable and start processing your ellipses at proper memory location.

Answer (score 2):

Use a const char* as the parameter before the ellipses.  As pointed out in the other answer, the behavior is undefined.

In addition, it looks like your log::message function has a memory leak.  You use malloc() without calling free(), and also not checking for NULL on return of malloc() (why are you using malloc() in a C++ program)